# Aplhanumeric characters Android in Multi languages

Tags: android, android-edittext, alphanumeric

My goal is to allow Alphanumeric characters in a "Last Name"  Edit Text Field.  I don't want the user to enter any smiley characters from Android keyboard. Preferred characters are (`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ123456789`) in Edit text widget.

IN XML layout file I am using the following code:

```
android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ123456789"
```

Does this code create a problem when the user is using my app in European languages like Greek etc ?

- What is the best way to make sure only Alphanumeric enters can be
  entered by user in all languages ?
- Does this prevent pasting unnecessary smiley characters in the Edit
  text field ? Please provide some better code if you have.